# Upgrade Laravel project from 5.5 to latest version 8

Tags: laravel

I want to Upgrade my Laravel project from (5.5 to 8) what I will do for that.
I didn't found any documents to upgrade from 5.5 to 8 just upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 or from 7 to 8 maybe must upgrade the project step by step from 5.5 to 5.6 the from 5.6 to 5.7 then .... nutil 8
Thanks

composer.json(Laravel 5.5):

```
{
"name": "HomFolio",
"description": "Smart Property Investing",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager": "dev-master",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "joedixon/laravel-translation": "^1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.7",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

composer.json (Laravel 8):

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to follow the steps given below:

1. Copy the your current `composer.json` file.
2. Now go here https://github.com/laravel-shift/laravel-8.x/blob/master/composer.json and copy `composer.json` file and replace with your existing `composer.json` file.
3. Again go to https://github.com/laravel-shift/laravel-8.x/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php and copy the `Handler.php` file and go to `app/exceptions/Handler.php` replace `Handler.php` with your existing file.
4. Run the command `composer update`.
5. Check your `old` or `your copied composer.json` file and if packages have been added to it then you can add packages through this command `composer require <package name>`.
6. Now, again run `composer update` command.

Comment: I followed these steps and it worked nicely.

Comment: you might be the life saver. great work.

Comment: upgraded from 5.6 to 8. worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Looks like upgrades are sequential. As of today, I have a laravel 5.7 project that I have to upgrade to Laravel 8 and this looks like the sequence I need to take. [image: Upgrade sequence]

Even when you opt for the highly recommended Laravel Shift, you have to pay for each upgrade as indicated in the picture below.

[image: Upgrade pricing].

If you have budget, laravel shift looks like a quick and easy way to go through the upgrade(s)

Answer (score 3):

You going to have to upgrade iteratively I'm afraid.

If you have the budget, you can use a service like Laravel Shift
to automate the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for pointing Laravel Shift, it saved heaps time on upgrading. Update from 5.5 to 8.x took only about a week with most time spend on rewrite functions for laravel excel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to some missing steps to @Krina Mangukiya

1. > /bootstrap/environment.php :
   >
   > $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::**createImmutable**(**DIR**.'/..');
   > $dotenv->load();
2. > The report and render methods of your application's
   > App\Exceptions\Handler class should accept instances of the Throwable
   > interface instead of Exception instances:
   >
   > use Throwable;
   >
   > public function report(**Throwable** $exception); public function
   > render($request, **Throwable** $exception);

**This answers have taken from stackoverflow only but would be go to have all issue answers in one place.**